# Use csvkit in a bash script to convert CSV to desired format?

Tags: python, bash, csv

I need to convert a large csv file into the static content format for Kirby CMS.

Say I have a csv file:

```
id,name,age,bio
0,bob,25,"Example bio, with a comma"
1,sam,37,"Hello World"
...
```

That I would like to restructure into separate folders/files like so:

1_bob/person.txt

```
ID: 0
----
Name: bob
----
Age: 25
----
Bio: Example bio, with a comma
```

2_sam/person.txt

```
ID: 1
----
Name: sam
----
Age: 37
----
Bio: Hello World
```

etc...

This is obviously a far more simplified version of my data, thus I had considered using `csvkit` because of its ability to properly parse commas in quoted fields etc.

I had found this script: https://forum.getkirby.com/t/import-from-csv/6038/15 which fails as a result of the above issue (the inability for basic bash IFS to read more complex CSV data)

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=";"
while read number year title website slug
do
  if [ ! -d "$number-$slug" ]; then
    mkdir ./$number-$slug
  fi
  echo -e "Year: $year\n----\nTitle: $title\n----\nWebsite: $website" > $number-$slug/project.txt
done < projects.csv
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

I know I could write a python script to do this faily easily but was wondering if there is indeed a way to combine any of the tooling of csvkit to do this in a bash script. My assumption was to use `csvcut` to pull lines of data out of the csv but of course am still at the same block of how to parse this data and output it into the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, much easier to process TSV files vs CSV files - with bash, awk and many utilities. It avoid the need for quoting. csvformat will handle the conersion:

Using your current script:

```
csvformat -T projects.csv | while IFS=$'\t' read number year title website slug
do
  if [ ! -d "$number-$slug" ]; then
    mkdir ./$number-$slug
  fi
  echo -e "Year: $year\n----\nTitle: $title\n----\nWebsite: $website" > $number-$slug/project.txt
done
```

The code expect 'slug' column for each record, which is not in the sample input. I'm assuming the actual input will have this in the 5th column